# How can I install a tub over this tub box?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement

In our unfinished basement, we have a roughed-in bath. I can see a water closet exit, a sink exit, and a tub exit.

The tub exit is covered by this product: http://www.oatey.com/products/rough-in-products/tub-box/tub-box. It's installed upside-down (the manufacturer's mark is reversed, hence my deduction). I have no affiliation with this company; this is the product the builder chose.

I tried peeling this off a bit without damaging it, and can see gravel beneath the concrete foundation. I'm not sure if there's a pipe or something else leading to the sewer from this point on.

Here's my question: What should I do with this, to be able to install a tub + surround combination in the basement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it out then install your tub.  This is there to make your life easier when connecting your tub drain.  If he laid concrete where box was you would have to break up the concrete around the PVC.  It doesn't matter if it is upside down or not...